# how to run python script which contains third party libraries using c#.Net?

Tags: python, c#-4.0, python-2.7, ironpython

I have created a python script, which consists of third party dll's. 
if i run it's executed properly. if run python script from c# application, 
i got an issue as shown below
"No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"

How can i rectify that one.

I am using import gdata.client library in my python script.

and my c# code is:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"c:\Subbu\PythonPractise\Sample\gdata-2.0.18\src");
paths.Add(@"c:\Subbu\PythonPractise\Sample\gdata-2.0.18");
paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"D:\Subbu\PythonPractise\API\SampleAPI.py");
```

Comment: Which version of (Iron)Python are you using? Could you provide the full python stack and a minimal source snippet from *SampleAPI.py*?

Answer (score 0):

You should add reference to assembly that you are trying to use.
From C# it would look something like this:

```
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile(@"Path\to\assemblyFile"));
```

or from python script:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("path\\to\\assemblyFile")
```